# Lucene search - score higher if word or similar are in a Field

Tags: java, text, lucene, field

I need to know when a word or words are inside a field in my index, and have that document swith greater score.

My problem is that if i search for "Sherton Hotel" I get this as greatest results

1. Petit Hotel
2. Crzy cow
3. Simmonss

And i would like this ones to have the greatest results

1. Maui Sheraton Hotel near the moon
2. A fantastic hotel that looks like Sheraton

I want that if the words Im searching or similar are inside, in this case, hotelName field they have a greater score.. besides the lenght of the field text.

I assume that for Lucene,
"Seraton Hotel" has more similarity with "Crazy Cow" than with "A fantastic hotel that looks like Sheraton".

Comment: Since "when a word or words are inside a field in my index, ... have that document swith greater score" is exactly what Lucene does, your use of it is probably at fault. Please post your indexing and searching code, along with the queries you're trying to execute.

Comment: agree with @synhershko, your question makes no sense. Pls. rephrase your question (with better diction and grammar) and/or better still post your code with the area you are having trouble with.

Comment: Ok, im changing a little my method and i will try to write something more clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`TermQuery` looks for exact matches, `FuzzyQuery` does things a little different. Without knowing what `hotelNameToSearch` and `hotel.getName().toLowerCase` are I can't really say whats going on, but why aren't you using the built-in queryParser? Just add a tilde (~) with a numeric value to indicate a fuzzy query?

Comment: Hi Synhershko, in my first approach I did it with queryParser and with greatest result but my boss dont want it that way.

No they want it to be done with TermFreqVector ...

Thanks for your help!